# Large String I/O

Tags: c++, string

how to take an input of string of length 100000 in c++. I have tried everything cin, gets, scanf, getline, getchar. but still nothing.
 please help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    string s="";
     for(int i=0;i<65535;i++){
        char c=getchar();
        s=s+c;
     }
     string s1="";
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        char c=getchar();
        s1=s1+c;
     }
    cout<<s1[1];
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/rC0U3q
there is no output for s1 for large strings

!!!I found The bug...it was limitation of ideone...thnx for responses

Comment: Why aren't you using getline again?

Comment: Surely building a string by concatenating one character at a time isn't a sane performance strategy..

Comment: If you want help you _must_ post the code with the problem. This code reads 65538 characters, therefore it does not have a 100000 character problem.

Comment: On which platform do you do this ?  Have you verified that on your platform 65535 < MAX_INT (in #include <climits>) ?  Is it possible that your console is expecting a '\n' ?  Are you aware that you only print the second char of the second string (which might be '\n' or space)  ?

Comment: its one line input.....and max_int>65535

Comment: On msvc13, if I add AAA to your input the code works as designed:  it prints "A".  It would be a safer practice for loops on the length to use size_t and SIZE_MAX instead of int and INT_MAX.

Comment: @christophe did u run it on your system

Comment: Yes of course !  With your input file to which I added AAA and a '\n'.  I ran the test from the console using a redirection (<input.txt) because I didn't want to type everything myself ;-)

Comment: @user224288: Is your question about the code running on ideone.com? Be aware that they impose a 64kB size limit on input and output.

Answer (score 0):

The following should read your input without any problem:

```
string s = "";
cout << "Max size of a string: " << s.max_size() << endl; // for info 
cin >> s; 
cout << "Result (" << s.size() << " bytes): " << s <<endl;
```

I tested it (MSVC13 on Win8) with the input that you gave, but with an extra newline at the end of the data (in a file with redirection), because `cin>>`  is generally line buferred and I don't want it to wait forever for a '\n'.

***Note:***  Your original code reads two strings s and s1 and only prints the second char of the second string.